# could vs might, different or same

Tags: modal-verbs

Is the difference between ***could*** and ***might*** in a) much more significant than in b)?

a) You need to discuss with them how they ***could vs might*** help you.

b) You ***could vs might*** try calling the help desk.

Can we put ***might=would perhaps*** in a)?

Comment: *Could* and *might* both have different meanings and uses. *Could* is used for *capability*. *Might* is used for *possibility*. The difference is apparent...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> a) You need to discuss with them how they *[could](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/could)* help you.

This would imply the question, "Do they have the ability or capacity to help you?"

> a) You need to discuss with them how they *might* help you.

This implies that they have the ability, but the question is, "In what ways [may](https://www.webster-dictionary.org/definition/May) they help you?"

> b) You *could*/*might* try calling the help desk.

In this instance, the implied meanings are similar enough to be almost identical; the difference, however would be in the tone--"could" implying a simple suggestion or even a mild command, while "might" is a polite suggestion with no implied command.

> Can we put might=would perhaps in a)?

I wouldn't. The phrase "would perhaps" is unnecessarily wordy and weak.

Comment: "Could" implies ability, "might" implies willingness.

Comment: Does the 'could' in "you could try calling..." mean "you have the ability to try calling..."?

Comment: I can't find any formal documentation to back up the opinion I'm about to give, but here it is: "you could try calling" I see as a colloquial construction used in conversation but to be avoided in writing. I would much prefer to see "you might try calling" for a suggestion or "you should try calling" if the intent is an imperative.

Answer (score 2):

In your examples, *could* and *might* mean the same thing. The word *can* would also fit.

In any of the three cases, you're being told talk to them to get their help. And in any of the three, their help not guaranteed.

The *perhaps* would change the voice but not the meaning. Only use it if you want to give the speaker a tentative voice.